# Which tempered distributions have the delta function as their derivative?

Tags: distribution-theory

I am looking for the general solution to the equation $T'= \delta_{x_0}$ where $T$ is a tempered distribution.

I started by using the following equality for derivatives of distributions:
$\langle T', \phi \rangle = - \langle T, \phi' \rangle \quad (I)$ where $\phi \in S$ (the space of Schwartz functions).

I am told to use the fact that, if a distribution satisfies $T'=0$ a constant $\alpha$ exists so that $T = \alpha$.

I wrote out the integral form of $(I)$ and plugged in $\alpha$ for $T$ and tried to integrate by parts but I am not getting near a solution. I would appreciate any sort of help!

Comment: I am NOT knowledgeable about tempered distributions.Sorry! However, I can tell you that the primitive of the Dirac delta function is the Heaviside step function. If you can convert the Heaviside function into a tempered distribution (by making sure it drops off sufficiently fast in the limit of x to +/- infinity) you have obtained the solution.

Comment: You might want to look at this book https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319140445. It can be helpful. See, e.g. Corolary 10.4.1 on page 144.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that it is assumed that you know that $H'=\delta,$ and consequently that $H'(x-x_0) = \delta(x-x_0).$

Let $T \in S'$ be such that $T'=\delta.$ Then $(T-H)' = T'-H' = \delta-\delta=0$ so $T-H = C$ for some constant $C.$ Thus all solutions to $T'=\delta$ can be written as $T=H+C,$ where $C$ is a constant.

Now, extend this argument to $T' = \delta_{x_0}.$

Comment: Why don't you think that $H$ is a tempered distribution?

Comment: $H$ is bounded and locally integrable. Therefore it's tempered. More generally, if $f$ is locally integrable and grows not faster than polynomially, then $f$ defines a tempered distribution. It's even possible for a function to grow exponentially in amplitude and still define a tempered distribution, e.g. $(\sin e^{x^2})' = 2x \, e^{x^2} \cos e^{x^2}$.

Comment: Indeed  there is an continuous injection $L^p(\mathbb{R}) \hookrightarrow S'(\mathbb{R})$ for $p \in [1,\infty]$ and $H(x) \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Answer (score 0):

The Heaviside function satisfy your requirements:

$$H(x) = \left \{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 \quad \text{if}  \quad x\geq 0 \\
0 \quad \text{if} \quad x <0
\end{array}\right.$$
It's distributional derivative satisfy $\frac{d}{dx}H=\delta_0$.